# Place the height of UITextView in CGFloat variable

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, cgfloat

I am resizing a `UITextView` based on its content. I would like to be able to then get the height of the textview and place it in a variable:

```
var heightFloat: CGFloat

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        let contentSize = self.definitionTextView.sizeThatFits(self.definitionTextView.bounds.size)
        var frame = self.definitionTextView.frame
        frame.size.height = contentSize.height
        self.definitionTextView.frame = frame

        heightFloat = contentSize.height
        NSLog("heightFloat = %@", heightFloat)

    }
```

And then when the application is ran, the console simply returns:

```
heightFloat = (null)
```

How do I get height of the textview be stored within `heightFloat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CGRectGetHeight` property.

```
heightFloat = CGRectGetHeight(self.definitionTextView.frame)
```